# How to delete multi-step variables session array

Tags: php

I have used the following method to eliminate the sessions of the multiple steps and even by separate variables.

```
if($payment === 'Completed'){
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['datos_form']);
    unset($_SESSION['__step__']);
    unset($_SESSION['formid']);
    unset($_SESSION['sPaso']);
    unset($_SESSION['Pending']);
    unset($_SESSION['p']);
    unset($_SESSION['step']);
    unset($step);
}
```

But the use of the `unset` function does not eliminate the steps

My PHP file where I keep the steps

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $step =  isset($_GET['step']) ?  $_GET['step'] : 1;
    $_SESSION['datos_form'] = $_POST;

    $datosForm = (isset($_SESSION['datos_form']) && is_array($_SESSION['datos_form'])) ? $_SESSION['datos_form'] :array();
    $sPaso = isset($datosForm['__step__']) ? $datosForm['__step__'] : 1;
    $step = isset($step) ? $step : $sPaso;
    $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'] = $step;

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $json =  array(
        'radio'     => $radio,
        'step'      => $step
    );

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I have performed a `var_dump ($ _ SESSION);` and a `print_r ($ GLOBALS);` obtaining the following information:

```
[_SESSION] => Array
    (
        [datos_form] => Array
            (
                [__step__] => 3
            )

        [4b228aaae2a6a7ce403bc4ecbc481de6] => ../libro.pdf
        [cart] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11
            )

        [qty] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [formid] => 64da7c62c643f40684f573acffb144eba6bfaf63
        [id_user] => 1
    )

)
```

Using `var_dump`:

```
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

When I go to step 1, the following change is obtained `[__step__] => 1` `string(1) "1"`:

```
[datos_form] => Array
    (
        [__step__] => 1
    )
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

When I go to step 2, the following change is obtained `[__step__] => 2` `string(1) "2"`:

```
[datos_form] => Array
    (
        [__step__] => 2
    )
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Comment: Your are unsetting `__step__` as a direct descendant of `$_SESSION` but it is a child of `$_SESSION[datos_form]` so you would need to do `unset($_SESSION[datos_form][__step__]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are unsetting `__step__` as a direct descendant of `$_SESSION` but it is a child of `$_SESSION[datos_form]`

To unset it you need to `unset($_SESSION[datos_form][__step__]);`

Comment: Thanks for answering, step 3 is maintained, it is not deleted :(

Comment: I have added my PHP file where I keep the steps

Comment: My answer is correct. The `unset`ting of things after `if($payment === 'Completed'){` needs to be modified.